# How to get text from element using Selenium through Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am writing an automated script for a website and would like to validate that a form was created. I have already created the form which I named "Blah!".

The webpage would now have a form with a column header "Name" that has 'Blah' displayed.

In the html file somewhere there will be a string called "Blah". I am trying to get html containing that string and set it to a variable, then do a comparison to see if that variable contains "blah" inside it. using python so this should look something like this:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Some_code_to_catch_the_html)
print ("blah" in x) #return true is x includes the string- form was created!
```

The code I have was able to run without any error except for the fact is not finding the text "blah!". 
Notes: the Div for "blah!" does not have a unique id and therefore I have to use the id for that block.

Actual code:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='dashboard-container-d08a6dcd-dc17-4662-9156-7fe74a4abc15']")
print(element[0].text)
assert "blah!" in element, "text not found in element"
# I have also used 'element without the index.
# here is the actual id for the table where 'blah!'is created under >> //*[@id='dashboard-container-d08a6dcd-dc17-4662-9156-7fe74a4abc15']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[5]/table/tbody
```

Under what circumstance would the text not get returned from the html?

Comment: Please don't put relevant info to the question in comments. It makes future readers have to read all the comments to make sure they have all the info to answer the question. Instead just edit the question and add the details there.

Comment: Did you google that error and look at all the questions and answers and try them? You didn't mention it. The first thing you should do when getting an error message is assume you aren't the first person to run into that error, someone else posted a question or blog or other info, and there are existing answers that you can try. Once you've looked through and tried a number of them, come back and edit your question and add some of the things you've tried so we don't have to suggest them or guess what you have or haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

To validate if any particular *Page Source* contains a certain element/text/form in it, you can search for the element/text/form within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) using `driver.page_source` and you can follow the below solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  driver.get("http://www.python.org")
  print("Don Powell" in driver.page_source)
  elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
  elem.clear()
  elem.send_keys("pycon")
  elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  print("Don Powell" not in driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  False
  True
  ```